# Modify variable in scope of a function in another function in the same scope (Python)

Tags: python, function, variables, scope

I have a variable `a` whose scope is in function `f()`.
There is another function `b()` in the scope of `f()`, where variable `a` is getting modified. How can I make sure the variable gets modified in function `b()` and is reflected correctly in the scope of function `f()`?

```
def f():
      a = 1
      def b():
             global a
             a = 2
      b()
      print(a)
 
f()

>>> 1  # expected is 2
```

Comment: Use the `nonlocal` keyword instead of global

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must replace `global` to `nonlocal`.